# How to replace special charactes like ",',/,\ with \",\',\/,\\ in android?

Tags: android, json

I would like to use special characters " ' / \ for constructing json. But while using those my json is breaking and getting json parsing error, so the solution is to replace every special chars with \" \' \ / so i had the following code.
After successful exectution its adding like double backslash. so whats the solution for that:

```
public void specialChars(String temp_string) {
    String[] charSet = new String[]{"\'", "\\", "/"};
    String newStr = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < charSet.length; i++) {
        String charStr = charSet[i];
        Log.e("String here " + i, charStr);
        if (temp_string.contains(charStr)) {
            newStr = temp_string.replace(charStr, "\\" + charStr);
            temp_string = newStr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use backslash to escape special caracters, like `\"` instead of plain `"`. Also to escape a \ you will need to use like \\ to escape the backslash.

Comment: i have to do that programatically, so is the following code, instead its adding double backslash to every special character. how to add single backslash programatically.

Comment: That will be straightforward using this `- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)`  This method *returns a new string in which all occurrences of a target string in the receiver are replaced by another given string.*

Comment: In case that helped you in any way then take a minute to accept the answer below, I have summarized everything we discussed here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have
private static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]";
In method you can have a code value.replaceAll(SPECIAL_CHARACTERS, "");

Answer (score 0):

Hoping it helped I will summarise our discussion from the comments here.

- use backslash to escape special caracters, like \" instead of plain ". Also to escape a \ you will need to use like \ to escape the backslash.
- to do this dynamically, 
  `public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`
- It *returns a new string in which all occurrences of a target string in the receiver are replaced by another given string.*

Comment: Not in IOS, in Android

Comment: Sorry my bad :p, let me replace that with android API. got carried away while helping a colleague here.

Comment: There you go. Replaced with Java String method.

Comment: Glad it helped, mark the answer as accepted to help people looking for answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`1.in first argument write the character you want to replace
 2.in second argument write the character you want to replace with.
  for example:
   String name=rohan kapoor
   name,replaceAll(" " ,"%20");
  here replace space with %20 in which you can access the string with space.`